# SSRS print to PDF - browser freezing and not saving file

Tags: pdf, service, printing, reporting-services, reporting

I have generated a report using SSRS 2005. I am trying to print to PDF (I have Adobe Acrobat 8 pro) and not export to PDF. For some reason, the web browser is freezing for like 10 minutes. After that, it is popping up the file selector to save the file in a path. When I click save, nothing happens. Did anyone face anything like this?

Comment: Your question is a bit too vague for us to answer, it's a guessing game for us (okay, just one guess then: is the report perhaps just way to large?). You'll need to debug this and get back to us with more info. Note that you can edit your question at any time to add more details (this will also bump your question).

Comment: Jeroen, thank you for your reply, but no the report is like 2 pages big and like 50 records. I tried the print to PDF on a couple of computers, still it did not work. When I try to print an excel or a website to PDF it works fine. This what got me to thinking that maybe SSRS does not support print to pdf. What else would you like to know?

Comment: SSRS doesn't care what printer it prints to (btw have you tried a regular printer yet?). Only issue I know of is that printing only decently works in IE. Either way, it's still a guessing game for us - you really need to debug this yourself and get back to us with more details.